# How does keras build batches depending on the batch-size?

Tags: keras, reshape

I'm trying to implement a Sentiment-Classifier using keras. But i got some problems with the batch_size param. It might be kind of a specific problem and I didn't find anything online that helped me.

Here is an example how the model could look:

```
Input_1                     Input_2             
(None, 200)                 (None, 200)
  |                            |
  |                            |   
Embedding_1                 Embedding_2
(None, 200, 200)            (None, 200, 200)
  |                            |
  |                            |
Reshape_1                   Reshape_2
(32, 200, 200)              (32, 200, 200)
    \                         /
     \                       /
      -----------        ----
                 \      /
                Concatenate(axis=2)
                (32,200,400)
                     |
                     |
                     ...
```

Reshaping is done by a Lambda-Layer using the reshape-function from keras.backend:

```
output = Lambda(lambda x: bd.reshape(x, (batch_size, 200, em_dim)), name='Reshape_Batch_size')(embedded)
```

I reshape the outputs of both embeddings (also using the batch_size) because the keras Concatenate-Layer needs tensors with equal shape on each axis except from the one you concat on. To be able to do the reshape I fit the number of my samples to a multiple of the batch_size. If I want to train my network everything is working fine until the last batch of the epoch. 
There I got an error that the number of input_values do not match the expected number:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a
>   tensor with 320000 values, but the requested shape has 1280000
>            [[Node: Reshape_Batch_size/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Embedding_basic_em/Gather,
>   Reshape_Batch_size/Reshape/shape)]]

```
320000 = 8 * 200 * 200
1280000 = 32 * 200 * 200
```

This looks like keras is cutting 24 samples from the last batch. But if I look at the output of the training it tells me there are 32 remaining samples:

```
Epoch 1/8 17440/17472 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5.1635 - acc: 0.6796
```

Does anybody know how keras handles batches depending on the given batch_size param or what I'm missing here? 
Or maybe someone has a hint how i can do the concatination without reshaping my outputs.

My Configuration:

I'm working on macOS Sierra version 10.12.6, using Python 3.5.3 from Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64). 
As keras backend I'm using tensorflow(1.4.0). Version of keras is 2.1.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the total amount of samples? It should certainly be a multiple of 32 for the last batch to have 32 samples. Otherwise, the size will use the "remaining" samples.

Test it:

```
assert len(x_train) % 32 == 0
```

### Are you sure you need reshaping?

Why do you need that reshape layer? In keras you simply cannot have different batch sizes for different tensors in the model unless you explicitly change these sizes in lambda layers.

Also, if the input shape is `(None, 200, 200)` and the output shape is `(32,200,200)`, you simply did nothing at all. The tensor gets out exactly the same.

**Just remove those reshape layers**